# rails search db for something like a return result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this at the moment

```
    tmname = Apple

    viaurldb = Via.where('tmname LIKE ?', 'product_name?').all
```

At the moment i have the `product_name` in the `Via` table.

I'm wanting it to be able to search the table for `tmname` and return the row whats in the table.

In the table i have `Granny Smiths Apples`

Afterwards im looking at doing the date of this. So in the table i have

```
  viadate = viaurldb.specifications.split(' ')[0]
```

Would the above, (depending if it finds anything in the viaurldb work?)

Thanks for any help or guidance

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your first query to:

```
tmname   = 'Apple'
viaurldb = Via.where('product_name ILIKE ?', "%#{tmname}%").first
```

Comment: Know this is a little different, But could i do another where inside? 

So i have tmdate, Can i do a where `tmdate == viadate?`

Comment: Yes you can do that too like `viaurldb = Via.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND viadate = ? ', ["%#{tmname}%", tmdate]).first`

Comment: doesn't this, `["%#{tmname}%", tmdate]` need to do this? `["%#{tmname}%", "%#{tmdate}%"]`

Comment: because i'm getting this happening `ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: product_name ILIKE ?`